# Vimeo oEmbed or iframe make webpage give a 403 Forbidden instead of a 200

Tags: html, http, iframe, vimeo, oembed

All right guys,

Here the strange behavior caused by a oEmbed/Vimeo (it's also true with a simple iframe code copied from the share button) on my webpage. First, the following webpage https://theprintatelier.com/ will rendered perfectly, showing an oEmbed video from Vimeo, there will be no error, everything looks fine.

Then, when you do a GET Request with Postman, or with Fetch As Google or any other SEO tools, I will get an 403 Forbidden response, which break any chance of the site being referenced in any search engine.

I know the root of the problem is the Vimeo Video on the page, when I take the video off the page, Bang! I get a 200 OK response from the HTTP request.

Do you guys have any idea to fix that strange problem? Or what can cause it?

Thanks :)

Comment: What video URL are you using in Postman that returns a 403 with oEmbed from Vimeo? The video's privacy settings on Vimeo may be set to limit its embed usage.

Comment: The URL that I'm using is https://theprintatelier.com/ which is the page that gave me a 403, on that page there's a embedded Vimeo video, when I remove the video, theprintatelier.com give me a 200 OK.

Comment: Odd issue. The videos linked in the page's source code are public videos so privacy settings interfering can be ruled out. Does this happen on other pages?  I suggest contacting Vimeo support at vimeo.com/help/contact to troubleshoot further (reference this Stack thread in your message).

Comment: Thanks, for now I replaced the video with a screenshot. The video is on another page, but it not embedded with a oEmbed, and it give me a 200. I’ll contact Vimeo. Thanks for your help.